# Missing "))" in shell script

Tags: shell, dash-shell

I'm really sorry I'm a total noob in shell scripting, I looked on the Internet and I didn't find the answer

> => /home/bee/Scripts/chkbsh: 11: /home/bee/Scripts/chkbsh: Syntax error: Missing '))'

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in $((gawk '/^#!.*( |[/])sh/{printf "%s\0", FILENAME} {nextfile}' /usr/bin/* 2>/dev/null) | xargs -0); do
checkbashisms "$file" >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ "$?" -gt 0 ]
then
    sed -i 's:^#!.*/bin/sh:#!/bin/bash:' "$file";
    echo "$file" has been processed!
fi
done
echo ":3"
```

If I change #!/bin/sh in #!/bin/bash everything is okay

Comment: Yes I use dash for /bin/sh :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have opening double parentheses, but two single closing parentheses. Place a space after the first `(`, like this:

```
for file in $( (gawk '/^#!.*( |[/])sh/{printf "%s\0", FILENAME}
              ^ there
```

BTW, it's always good advice to test your scripts with [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), this way you could have easily spotted above error.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
for file in `gawk '/^#!.*( |[/])sh/{printf "%s\0", FILENAME} {nextfile}' /usr/bin/* 2>/dev/null | xargs -0`; do
checkbashisms "$file" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Using a deprecated syntax isn't a good workaround for this kind of issue

Comment: Thanks for the thanks, setting as accepted answer would be appreciated. The syntax is correct and POSIX compatible and more legible as the execution command contains parenthesis, that's why I proposed the back-tic which is not formally deprecated. In this case, the style is better.